# Do or don't I need to create a table that I want to prepopulate with H2?

Tags: database, hibernate, h2, in-memory-database

I'm confused by the errors I get when trying to create an in-memory H2 DB for my Spring Boot application. The relevant configuration is

```
db.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=runscript from 'classpath:create.sql'
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

And `create.sql`:

```
CREATE TABLE `cities` (
  `name` varchar(45)  NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`)
) ;

INSERT INTO `cities` VALUES ('JAEN'),('ALBACETE');
```

But I get the error `Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "CITIES" already exists;`

Weird is, if I remove the `CREATE TABLE` statement, I get:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "CITIES" not found;
```

The only thing that works is using `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS`, but well, I don't think I should need to.

What's going on? What's the proper way of pre-populating static data into an H2 memory DB?

Answer (score 1):

1) Hibernate way: use import.sql file or specify files

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files=file1.sql,file2.sql`

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

2) Spring Boot: use default schema.sql & data.sql files
or specify files through properties

`spring.datasource.schema = file1.sql
 spring.datasource.data = file1.sql, file2.sql`

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html